# Is there any different while setting metadata of Everyplay on Android and IOs

Tags: android, ios, everyplay

This code below seems to work on Android:

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("name", username);
            Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("score", score);
#endif
```

However, it's show "metadata missing" if I want to share replay on IOs. 
Am I missing something? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata is same on ios and Android unless you specify otherwise
like

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("level_name", levelName);
```

You have to add the metadata on the website https://developers.everyplay.com/

Then if you want to use that metadata in the video title you can add that there 
example

```
{gamename} instant replay:  {level_name} !
```

where level_name is metadata key for level name

Finally make sure you start recording the video before you pass meta data

```
Everyplay.SharedInstance.StartRecording();
Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("level_name", levelName);
```

That worked for me on ipad hope it helps